# how to reset the control values inside the modal pop up using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="popup" TargetControlID="cmdTrigger" 
            PopupControlID="pnlPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            OkControlID="btnOk" >
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>  
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup" Style="display: none">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="msg" Text="Add a new Entry" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="close" OnClientClick="$find('popup').hide(); return false;" />
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="msg" Text="Name" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="346px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="48px"   />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="50px" OnClientClick="$find('popup').hide(); return false;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

This is my code. Once I have  written  some thing in textbox  and I click the cancel  button, by which the pop up window  will  close.
If I try to open the pop up window  again, the textbox will still hold its previous entered value.  so is there any  way I can clear the  value which I have  entered in the textbox,  using Javascript, jQuery.  I don't want to use a  server  side  event  for this  which will  do a post back event so
what are my options?

Comment: you need to place four spaces before code so it formats correctly and it is not "eaten" by the sanitizer. Or you can select the text and use the button with the ones and zeros in it.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the textbox when you click cancel...?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="50px"
   OnClientClick="$find('txtName').value = '';
                  $find('popup').hide();
                  return false;" />
```

Comment: Note: I am not sure what this `$find` function of yours is actually doing.

Comment: $find   here is   used to find the   pop  up  control whichw e  would  like  to hide  or  show

Comment: Well, you get the idea.  Find the `txtName` control and set its value to "" when they click the cancel button.  Simple as that.